Are there non ballistic/pyrotechnic parachutes for airplanes?
Is there an aircraft parachute system that doesn't use brs / pyrotechnic ejection for its deployment?
I'm thinking something simple like ones used in skydiving or with a  spring mechanism as used in this drag chute:

(source)
video
NOTE: The question is limited to parachutes for deployments in the air. (I.e.: Parachutes for braking purposes on the ground are excluded)

I thought there was only one certified whole aircraft parachute system?

@AnonymousPhysicist if you are referring to Cirrus they are not the only one, they made it popular, but you can even put a parachute on a 182 if you want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eo7ZmcAWxwk

@AnonymousPhysicist Cirrus planes (SR20/22 and SF50) have a parachute uniquely certified and factory installed as part of the type certificate. A number of other planes, including the Cessna 150, 172/182 have a system certified as a third-party aftermarket modification under the supplemental type certificate (STC) process.

@user71659 Right, and are all those type certificates really for the same product?

BRS makes (almost all of) them. The product varies based on gross weight but they are very similar.

Your title said "airplanes", but in your body of text you said "aircraft".

Is there an aircraft parachute system that doesn't use brs /
pyrotechnic ejection for its deployment?

Hang gliders and paragliders are ultralights, which are considered "aircraft" in the US.  (See ASE answer In the United States, are ultralights legally considered aircraft?. )
Hang gliders and paragliders usually have hand-tossed parachute deployment bags, located on the pilot's harness.  These parachutes lower the glider and pilot together as one unit.
Here is a link showing deployment of such a parachute during an incident where a hang glider accidentally got lifted up into a cloud and entered a high-G turn and the pilot was concerned about loss of consciousness, and failure of the pilot harness, as well as breakup of the glider itself.  (The pilot had no idea which direction to roll the glider to exit the turn.)  The video is set to open at 4:28 which is a few seconds before the parachute deployment.  You'll have to play around with pausing the video to hope to glimpse the actual hand-thrown deployment bag, but you can easily see the long parachute bridle.




Of interest is the fact that the vario seems to be occasionally playing some "lift" tones even immediately after the deployment.  Wow.  Talk about "cloud suck".

Also of interest--look at the direction of the parchute bridle relative to the camera at 4:37 or 4:48.  Clearly the glider is inverted here.  The pilot outweighs the glider, thus the chute's pull is not sufficient to pull the pilot to a position above the glider, the pilot is below the glider. The glider is inverted.  Around 5:11 things change, and the pilot ends up above the glider, with the (now upright) glider hanging below him.

It would be sweet if the video continued till landing or at least till exiting the cloud, but unfortunately it does not.
